# Haskell language server and go to library sources

Tags: haskell

Is there a possibility to use vscode along with haskell LS to have possibility to go to definitions of functions in third-party or built-in libraries?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: only with [codex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codex) which downloads sources of dependencies and builds tags for them. far from perfect but the best I could achieve

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks!